# AnyLogic schedule for arrival rate

Tags: schedule, anylogic

I want to use a schedule for my arrival rate. e.g. I want 33 trucks to arrive randomly between 08:00 and 09:00 and so on.

I added a rate schedule starting 8 till 9 and entered a value of 0.55

So it looked like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJubj.jpg

But when I started my simulation there were just 24 trucks within this period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want exactly 33 trucks to arrive randomly between 8am and 9am you can do this:

1) create an event that runs cyclically ever day at 8am

2) create a dynamic event called GenerateTruck .

3) put the following code in the action of the event:

```
for(int i=0;i<33;i++){
    double rand=uniform(0, 1);
    create_GenerateTruck(rand,HOUR);

}
```

4) put the following code in the action of the dynamic event

```
source.inject();//assuming a source generates your trucks
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your schedule type to be "Rate" and set it up as below:

[image]

Learn all about it in the [AnyLogic help](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fdata%2FSchedule.html&resultof=%22%73%63%68%65%64%75%6C%65%22%20%22%73%63%68%65%64%75%6C%22%20)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I do so, I just get here 78 units, but it should be 94 in total.. https://imgur.com/a/81c1Z9h @ source I choose rate schedule, but I think this should be right, or?

Comment: A rate-based schedule is stochastic. You will never get the exact arrivals and it will vary with each simulation run (if you vary the random seed). This is what you asked for, no? ("I want 33 trucks to arrive randomly between 08:00 and 09:00 and so on.")

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. I got it now, but would there be a way to have exactly this amount of trucks between a certain period of time?

Comment: Use Felipe's suggestion below. But from a modelling perspective, this is almost always a bad way to do things. Your system does not have exactly 33 arrivals for sure. And even if your data says that, it would vary in reality.